# How to determine if a checkbox is selected or not, using selenium, if the only clue is a CSS "::before" and "::after"?

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

Here is a checkbox Selecting the checkbox adds "::after" into the innerHTML. Un-selecting removes it. That's the only clue I have to determine if it is checked or not.
[image]

I tried:
`checkbox.get_attribute('outerHTML')`.
It gives the output  `'<label _ngcontent-caf-c4="" for="all">&nbsp;</label>'`
See, the output does not include `::before` and `::after`.

`checkbox.get_attribute('innerHTML')` gives the output: `'&nbsp;'`

It returns all other properties such as:
`cbox.value_of_css_property('font-family')` output:
`'Metropolis, "Avenir Next", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif'`
And `cbox.value_of_css_property('content')` output:
`'normal'`

Is there a better way to know if the checkbox (label element) is selected (using Selenium in Python 3.8)?
Or, is Selenium not capable of giving this clue?

Comment: Your selecting the label not the input.  Can you access the is_selected property if you select the input as the object?

Comment: @RichEdwards: Intuitively input should be the check box element. But it is not responding and has no change for selection or unselection. Click() also doesn't work there. I first tried it on input element, before moving to label. Input has no much properties, no inner html as well.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [RichEdwards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13841248/richedwards) for the idea, I got the solution for this. Here it is:

`.click()` works on element with `'label'` tag.
`.is_selected()` works on element with `'input'` tag

After each `.click()` call on `'label'`, we need to get the elements freshly (in my case I did with `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`) and then call `.is_selected()` on `'input'`, it says `True` or `False`. True if checked, False if unchecked.

Each .click() is somehow making the elements stale. So getting theelements freshly is necessary. As of now I am new to javascript and angular. I appreciate helpful comments from experts.